# How to change password of LDAP user?

Tags: linux, password, ldap, openldap, passwd

Is it possible to change password for logged in LDAP user using passwd command?

I have logged in to server1 using testuser. Trying to change password for itself (testuser) and got the below error.

```
[testuser@server1 ~]$ passwd  
Changing password for user testuser.  
(current) LDAP Password:  
New password:  
Retype new password:  
password change failed: Insufficient access  
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/340340/400278) answer. You need to set an acl to allow the user to change his or her own password.

Comment: Put something like this in your `cn=config`, `olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none`

Comment: Did you try to use $ ldappasswd command?